# QQuickFramebufferObject is flipped on Y axis in QML

Tags: qt, opengl, qml

I have created a new QML project, and I use a custom QML item to integrate raw OpenGL.

If I take a screenshot using `framebufferObject()->toImage().save("a.png");`
in the QQuickFramebufferObject::Renderer then the surface is correctly renderer, but the QML surface is flipped on Y-axis.

To fix that, I need to scale my matrix by -1 on Y-axis, but now my screenshot is flipped. I think that the flip come from QML vs OpenGL coordinates. Can someone give me a the QML to render properly instead of scaling my matrix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer from qt-project's forum : http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/48124/.
It links to the following bug report: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-41073

Answer (score 2):

just override the function `QSGNode *QQuickFramebufferObject::updatePaintNode(QSGNode *, UpdatePaintNodeData *)` with

```
QSGNode* QVTKFrameBufferObjectItem::updatePaintNode(
    QSGNode *const inOutNode, UpdatePaintNodeData *const inOutData) {
  const int width = this->width();
  const int height = this->height();
  QMatrix4x4 flipY;
  flipY.translate(width*0.5, height*0.5);
  flipY.scale(1.0, -1.0);
  flipY.translate(-width*0.5, -height*0.5);
  inOutData->transformNode->setMatrix(flipY);
  return QQuickFramebufferObject::updatePaintNode(inOutNode, inOutData);
}
```

Comment: This solution overrides the transform that may be assigned to the item through QML. Besides the vertical mirroring will be applied to all child items (if any). However this answer helped me to arrive at the [**right solution**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39082403/6394138).

Answer (score 1):

In your custom item (which is of course a sub-class of `QQuickFramebufferObject` ) override the `updatePaintNode()` method as follows:

```
QSGNode* updatePaintNode(QSGNode* oldNode, UpdatePaintNodeData* upnData)
{
    QSGNode* node = QQuickFramebufferObject::updatePaintNode(oldNode, upnData);
    QSGSimpleTextureNode& textureNode = dynamic_cast<QSGSimpleTextureNode&>(*node);
    textureNode.setTextureCoordinatesTransform(QSGSimpleTextureNode::MirrorVertically);
    return node;
}
```